# rails: loop within loop error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody tell, why this code works?

```
    <% @products.each do |p| %>
         <%= link_to p.name, product_path(p.id), :class => "title" %>
    <%end%>
```

And this doesn't?

```
    <% @products.in_groups_of(2).each do |product_array| %>
        <% product_array.each do |p| %>
          <%= link_to p.name, product_path(p.id), :class => "title" %>
        <% end %>
    <%end%>
```

The code gives error of undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass.
I am not getting clue of it. Can anybody help?

Comment: is it giving you an error? Can you tell us what it is?

Comment: @sevenseacat undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appends `nil` if there is not enough records, that is why it gives `nil:NilClass` error

```
>> %w(1 2 3).in_groups_of(2)        # => [["1", "2"], ["3", nil]]
>> %w(1 2 3).in_groups_of(2,false)  # => [["1", "2"], ["3"]]
```

see [in_groups_of(number, fill_with = nil)](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of)

```
<% @products.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |product_array| %>
    <% product_array.each do |p| %>
      <%= link_to p.name, product_path(p.id), :class => "title" %>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an odd number of products. If you try and split an odd number into groups of two, the final product in the last group will be nil. You can just add:

```
unless p.nil?
  <%= link_to p.name, product_path(p.id), :class => "title" %>
end
```

to ensure that you have an instance.

Comment: yeah, You are right. whats the solution for this?